# How do I fix AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing the greedy gift-givers problem for USACO training and I keep getting an "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'" error. Here is my code:

```
fin = open('gift1.in','r')
p= fin.readline().split(",")
np = int(p.strip())
dictOfMoney = { fin.readline().strip() : 0 for i in range(np) }

while(True):
    giver = fin.readline().strip()
    if(giver==""):
        break
    amount, divided = map(int, fin.readline().strip().split())
    receivers = [fin.readline().strip() for i in range(divided)]

    try:
        quotient, remainder = divmod(amount,divided)
    except:
        quotient = remainder = 0

    for receiver in receivers:
        dictOfMoney[receiver] += quotient
    dictOfMoney[giver] += -amount + remainder

with open('gift1.out','w') as fout:
    for name, money in dictOfMoney.items():
        fout.write(f"{name} {money}\n")
```

A sample input for gift1.in is:

```
5
dave
laura
owen
vick
amr
dave
200 3
laura
owen
vick
owen
500 1
dave
amr
150 2
vick
owen
laura
0 2
amr
vick
vick
0 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `p` is a list. What did you expect `p.strip()` to do?

Comment: @khelwood I wanted it to separate the list and make them numbers. I'm sorry if this seems dumb but I've only recently started coding in python.

Comment: You seem to be trying to convert `p`, a list, into a single int `np`. Since that doesn't make sense, it is hard to advise you.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the list into multiple separate ints. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: You can do that, but then `range(np)` doesn't make sense in the next line.

Comment: so what would you recommend I do?

Comment: Start with a smaller program, get each line working in turn, understand what you're writing. Use type hints if you're struggling to keep track of what types things are.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a `list`. Lists don't have a `strip()` function. Even if they did, `int(p.strip())` would throw an error because you can't convert a list to an integer.

To apply a function to each element of a list, you need to write out the code to do that:

```
np = [int(elem.strip()) for elem in p]
```

The `[... for ... in ...]` construct is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: When I include this piece of code, it throws this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 5'

Comment: Why do you think it throws that error? I encourage you to read the error message and try to understand why it's happening. [Debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is an important part of programming, and the sooner you learn how to debug your programs effectively the better. Hint: Does `split(",")` do what you want to do to the line?

Comment: I think it is because of the space between the characters, is there a way I can remove them and replace it with a comma? and if so would that work?

Comment: Why replace the spaces with a comma in your input string when you know it's going to be a space? Why not just `split()` on spaces in the first place?

Comment: I've done that now, and it no longer shows that error but as khelwood said earlier the range no longer works.

Comment: I echo khelwood's suggestion when you asked them what you should do. _Start with a smaller program, get each line working in turn, understand what you're writing._ Also read the documentation. Why should `range(np)` work? What do you _actually_ want to do? What does `range()` expect, and what are you passing to it? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges